# IPython Essentia 'no module named' error

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use a Python module called **Essentia** which is used for audio analysis. In order to use that, it has to be built in Ubuntu Environment as explained [here](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/installing.html). I did all the things to install `Essentia` in a folder in desktop.

Then in `IPython`, I am trying to import the installed and built `Essentia` module. I am running `IPython` in the folder where my module is located. It is not in `/usr/lib/python2.7`. It is located in my desktop as mentioned above.

But when I import Essentia module in IPython, it tells me

> ImportError: No module named essentia

What is the problem here? Do I have to build Essentia inside `/usr/lib/python2.7`, and if so, how do I do that? Or has some other thing gone wrong?

Comment: please add the output of `which -a python` and `which -a ipython`

Comment: `which -a python` output is `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: `which -a ipython` output is `/usr/local/bin/ipython`

Comment: "I am running IPython in the folder where my module is located": I think you'll need to tell/show us what is in that folder? You may need to go one folder up or down, or change something, to have your import statement behave properly

Comment: What exactly is your import statement? `import essentia`?

Comment: That folder is in which my module is located. Inside that I have the waf file of the module. I have put that folder in my Desktop.

Comment: Import statement is `import essentia`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and was able to fix it.

From your question I can't be 100% sure what your problem is - however, these are a couple of possible culprits which you - or others - may be having.

I, too, am using Python 2.7, and want to use Essentia in an IPython/Jupyter Notebook environment.

### 1. Essentia location

*This is my first guess as to what your problem is.*

If you were able to successfully configure and install Essentia (otherwise see below), the path where the Essentia Python files were likely installed is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` or similar, and that Python isn't looking there. To make sure it does, you could add

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```

to the start of your Python script.

## This solved it for me.

You could also add the following line to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

to avoid having to add this path to every Python file/Notebook where you would like to use Essentia.

### 2. Configuration and installation

*Skip this if you were able to successfully configure and install Essentia. These were other notable issues I had before I finally got the `install finished successfully` message.*

The main instructions, as OP noted, are [here](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/installing.html).

#### ffftw3f or taglib not found

I resolved this using MacPorts instead:

```
sudo port install fftw-3-single
sudo port install taglib
```

#### Failed installation

I should note I had some issues during installation which made me get rid of the C++ tests, Gaia, and Vamp plugin support (none of which I needed) by removing these and some others from the config line ([as this has helped other users in the past](https://github.com/MTG/essentia/issues/210)):

```
./waf configure --mode=release --with-python --with-examples
```

instead of

```
./waf configure --mode=release --build-static --with-python --with-cpptests --with-examples --with-vamp --with-gaia
```

This made the following error message go away:

```
Build failed
 -> task in 'standard_fadedetection' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 4417706448: cxxprogram standard_fadedetection.cpp.5.o -> standard_fadedetection}
['clang++', '-stdlib=libc++', 'src/examples/standard_fadedetection.cpp.5.o', '-o', '/Users/Brecht/Downloads/essentia-2.0.1/build/src/examples/standard_fadedetection', '-Lsrc', '-lessentia', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-lfftw3f', '-lyaml', '-lavformat', '-lavcodec', '-lavutil', '-lswresample', '-lsamplerate', '-ltag']
 -> task in 'streaming_extractor_freesound' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 4417783952: cxxprogram FreesoundExtractor.cpp.22.o,FreesoundLowlevelDescriptors.cpp.22.o,FreesoundRhythmDescriptors.cpp.22.o,FreesoundSfxDescriptors.cpp.22.o,FreesoundTonalDescriptors.cpp.22.o,streaming_extractor_freesound.cpp.22.o -> streaming_extractor_freesound}
['clang++', '-stdlib=libc++', 'src/examples/freesound/FreesoundExtractor.cpp.22.o', 'src/examples/freesound/FreesoundLowlevelDescriptors.cpp.22.o', 'src/examples/freesound/FreesoundRhythmDescriptors.cpp.22.o', 'src/examples/freesound/FreesoundSfxDescriptors.cpp.22.o', 'src/examples/freesound/FreesoundTonalDescriptors.cpp.22.o', 'src/examples/streaming_extractor_freesound.cpp.22.o', '-o', '/Users/Brecht/Downloads/essentia-2.0.1/build/src/examples/streaming_extractor_freesound', '-Lsrc', '-lessentia', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-L/opt/local/lib', '-lfftw3f', '-lyaml', '-lavformat', '-lavcodec', '-lavutil', '-lswresample', '-lsamplerate', '-ltag']
```

Let me know how that works out - I've got a feeling I've had about all the errors you could encounter.

(**Acknowledgement:** *The main reason I was able to solve this so quickly is [this thread](https://github.com/MTG/essentia/issues/113) - also thanks to [@djmoffat](https://twitter.com/djmoffat) and [@justin_salamon](https://twitter.com/justin_salamon).*)

Answer (score 0):

I had some difficulties installing on Mac OS 10.14.5

This solved it for me:

- Created a virtual environment with conda, Python v3.7
- Installed essentia with homebrew: `brew install essentia --HEAD`

After that I looked up where Homebrew puts the site packages and used this code to import and use essentia in a Jupyter notebook:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages")

import essentia
```